# SQL transform rows into columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, rows, col

My goal is to transform this:

table1:

```
ID  Day Status
101 1   N
101 2   P
101 3   N
101 4   P
101 5   R
102 1   P
102 2   P
102 3   R
102 4   R
102 5   R
103 2   N
103 3   N
103 4   P
103 5   P
104 3   P
104 4   P
104 5   R
105 4   N
105 5   N
```

Into this:

table2:

```
ID  1   2   3   4   5
101 N   P   N   P   R
102 P   P   R   R   R
103     N   N   P   P
104         P   P   R
105             N   N
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Access*, you could use:

```
TRANSFORM First([Status]) AS Status
SELECT [ID]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [ID]
PIVOT [Day];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your "day" is a limited range (1..7 ?) then yes, it's a bit tedious but doable:

```
SELECT Id, MAX(CASE Day WHEN 1 THEN Status END) AS "1"
         , MAX(CASE Day WHEN 2 THEN Statue END) AS "2"
FROM Table GROUP BY Id ORDER BY Id
```

The CASE returns either Status or NULL in each column. MAX() collapses that down to a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use the pivot table function to achieve your need.
hope this helps.

```
SELECT *

FROM
(SELECT ID, status, day
    FROM  yourtable) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
max(status)
FOR day IN (1,2,3,4,5)
) AS PivotTable;
```